# Tomcat started but cannot access to localhost

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, localhost, liferay

I try  since this morning to install a virtual box on my computer in order to work with liferay.

I downloaded the liferay bundle with tomcat on their official website and openjdk to go with. When I launch the script ./startup.sh, Tomcat seems to start perfect as I have the following message :

```
    marine@marine-VirtualBox:~/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/bin$ ./startup.sh 
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
    Using CLASSPATH:       /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Tomcat started.
```

But, event after waiting several minutes, I cannot access to my localhost (or 127.0.0.1)....

I tried to change the port number of Tomcat from 8080 to 8090 : same result...

I looked into the logs folder of the server. Eight files are in :

```
    catalina.2016-11-02.log  
    catalina.out    
    host-manager.2016-11-02.log   
    localhost.2016-11-02.log  
    localhost_access_log.2016-11-02.txt  
    manager.2016-11-02.log
```

The first one contains :

```
     marine@marine-VirtualBox:~/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/logs$ cat catalina.2016-11-02.log 
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.067 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.32.0
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-45-generic
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/logging.properties
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Duser.timezone=GMT
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/endorsed
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/temp
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.286 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.315 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.317 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.318 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.323 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1098 ms
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.371 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.371 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
     02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.395 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
```

The second ones contains :

```
    marine@marine-VirtualBox:~/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/logs$ cat catalina.out 
     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.067 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.32.0
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-45-generic
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/logging.properties
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Duser.timezone=GMT
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/endorsed
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/temp
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.286 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.315 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.317 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.318 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.323 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1098 ms
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.371 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.371 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:31.395 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
    02-Nov-2016 14:02:46.847 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    Loading jar:file:/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
    Loading jar:file:/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
    Loading jar:file:/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
    14:02:53,461 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:75] Determine dialect for HSQL Database Engine 2.3
    14:02:53,953 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:93] Liferay is configured to use Hypersonic as its database. Do NOT use Hypersonic in production. Hypersonic is an embedded database useful for development and demonstration purposes. The database settings can be changed in portal-ext.properties.
    14:02:53,955 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:148] Found dialect com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.HSQLDialect
    14:03:09,144 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.200.v20150831-0856 [0]
    14:03:11,984 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.util.taglib_2.4.1 [1]
    14:03:12,032 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.osgi.util_3.0.2 [2]
    14:03:12,059 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.petra.xml_1.0.3 [3]
    14:03:12,075 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.configuration.metatype_2.0.3 [4]
    14:03:12,341 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence_2.0.1 [5]
    14:03:12,459 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.log4j.extender_2.0.2 [6]
    14:03:12,640 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.lpkg.deployer_2.0.5 [7]
    14:03:12,673 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.portlet.tracker_2.0.3 [8]
    14:03:12,691 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper_2.1.2 [9]
    14:03:12,719 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler_2.0.7 [10]
    14:03:12,739 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender_2.0.7 [11]
    14:03:12,771 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.generator_2.1.9 [12]
    14:03:13,214 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.reference.support_1.0.3 [13]
    14:03:13,229 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.profile_1.0.2 [14]
    14:03:13,246 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.target.platform.indexer_4.0.0 [16]
    14:03:13,271 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.sun.el.javax.el_3.0.0 [17]
    14:03:13,280 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED javax.servlet.jsp-api_2.3.2.b01 [18]
    14:03:13,304 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.3.LIFERAY-PATCHED-2 [19]
    14:03:13,326 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api_1.2.1 [20]
    14:03:13,349 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.aries.jmx.api_1.1.1 [21]
    14:03:14,065 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.aries.jmx.core_1.1.3 [22]
    14:03:14,200 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.aries.util_1.0.0 [23]
    14:03:14,559 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.1 [24]
    14:03:14,713 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.commons.io_1.4.0 [25]
    14:04:02,934 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.felix.bundlerepository_2.0.2 [26]
    14:04:04,302 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.felix.configadmin_1.8.8 [27]
    14:04:04,555 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.felix.dependencymanager_3.2.0 [28]
    14:04:04,746 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell_3.2.0 [29]
    14:04:17,130 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 20dba70a-05a1-0016-1777-90ecdf793026][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.felix.eventadmin_1.4.6 [30]
```

The three others files are empty.

When I try to shutdown the server with the corresponding scripts, I have the following message :

```
    marine@marine-VirtualBox:~/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/bin$ ./shutdown.sh 
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
    Using CLASSPATH:       /home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/marine/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Nov 02, 2016 3:16:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
    SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
    Nov 02, 2016 3:16:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
    SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
            java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

So.. I guess my server has not been really started. But why ? Do you have any idea of the reason ? I looked in other posts woith similar promblems but nothing was positive.

Thanks,

Marine

EDIT : My configuration is now running. But ... I don"t exactly know why, it just "broke up". I've probably change something in my configuration or another process stop running. Thanks !

Comment: I had similar problems but they are more lilke glitches on my dev environment. Here is a suggestion: ensure all previous processes are not running (using `jps` e `kill`) and then start tomcat with `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run`. This will run the process synchronously, with the log going out in the terminal. It may be more helpful! Note also that Liferay 7 can take a long time to boot depending on the machine. (In mine with 8GB of RAM I can take 5 to 10 minutes if I'm using other programs.)